# IE6 image scaling with bicubic filter

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-6, image-scaling, bicubic

I have a project where I have to resize some images in the actual browser side.

IE8, FF3 et al all apply a filter to smooth the resizing of the image, so in these browsers everything looks good.

In IE7 I have applied the following fix which works great:
    -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;

In IE6 however I can only find references to the AlphaImage Filter (the same one used to enable alpha transparency on PNG files).  However I can't find an example of how to use it, nor have I been able to get it working myself.

Can anyone provide me with an example?  Preferably applied to actual img tags, though I could use background images if required.

MSDN link (for what its worth): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969%28VS.85%29.aspx

The code I am using in my CSS is applied to the img, though I've tried applying it to the img container as well (with no effect):

```
#provider-list li img {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="/image.gif", sizingMethod="scale");
}
```

A thousand thank you's in advance :)

Rick

Answer (score 0):

I believe most (if not all) versions of the IE5/6 PNG transparency fix use the same property. Looking at their code might be a good place to at least get the property working, at which point you can tweak it for your own use.

http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/

http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/